# jquery ajax response is not appending to my Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I am trying to create a couple of html elements for my page after my jquery ajax response. i do get a response back which is correct, but i wish to be able to create some elements to help display my response.

I think i have created them right in jquery but after appending, the newly created elements do not append to div, but it works if i append to a table. Please help me spot what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Here is my HTML below

```
        <h3>Interest</h3>
    <div>
        <p runat="server" id="pInterest">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddInterest" CssClass="btnAddCommunity" Text="Add Interest" OnClientClick="return false;" />
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOnlineCommunities" OnItemDataBound="rptOnlineCommunities_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div id="tblUseCommunities" class="dvOnlineCommunityMain">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div runat="server" id="dvOnlineCommunity" class="dvOnlineCommunity">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOnlineCommunityDescription" CssClass="lblOnlineCommunityDescription"></asp:Label>

                        <p runat="server" id="pOnlineCommunityDetails"></p>

                        <a runat="server" id="linkOnlineCommunity" target="_blank"></a>
                        <p class="pCommunityBtns">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <div runat="server" id="dvOnlineCommunity" class="dvOnlineCommunity">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOnlineCommunityDescription" CssClass="lblOnlineCommunityDescription"></asp:Label>
                        <p runat="server" id="pOnlineCommunityDetails"></p>
                        <a runat="server" id="linkOnlineCommunity" target="_blank"></a>
                        <p class="pCommunityBtns">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </div>                   
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </p>
```

javascript function bellow

```
function UpdateOnlineCommunity(communityId, communityName, communityDescription, communityLink) {
var serviceData = JSON.stringify({
    'communityId': communityId,
    'communityName': communityName,
    'communityDescription': communityDescription,
    'communityLink': communityLink
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PresentationService.asmx/UpdateUserCommunity",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: serviceData,
    success: function(response) {
        var data = response.d;

        var dvOnlineCommunityMain = $("#dvOnlineCommunityMain");

        var dvOnlineCommunity = $('<div/>', {
            id: "dvOnlineCommunity",
            class: "dvOnlineCommunity",
            "data-id": data.CommunityID
        });

        var lblOnlineCommunityDescription = $('<span/>', {
            id: "lblOnlineCommunityDescription",
            text: data.Description
        });

        var pOnlineCommunityDetails = $('<p/>', {
            id: "pOnlineCommunityDetails",
            text: data.Detail
        });

        var linkOnlineCommunity = $('<a/>', {
            id : "linkOnlineCommunity",
            href : data.Link,
            text: data.Link
        });

        var btnUpdateOnlineCommunity = $('<button/>', {
            id: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            class: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            text: "Update"
        });

        var btnDeleteOnlineCommunity = $('<button/>', {
            id: "btnDeleteOnlineCommunity",
            class: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            text: "Delete"
        });

        dvOnlineCommunity.append(lblOnlineCommunityDescription, pOnlineCommunityDetails, linkOnlineCommunity,
            btnUpdateOnlineCommunity, btnDeleteOnlineCommunity);

        dvOnlineCommunityMain.append(dvOnlineCommunity);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `dvOnlineCommunityMain`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry i accidentally to that out, but i have added it right after the declaration of "data".. but still this doesnt work

Comment: I'd like to test your code on jsfiddle. Can you post the real HTML instead of the ASP.net template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `id` selector as `dvOnlineCommunityMain`, but in your html it is defined as `class`. Hence the issue.

```
 <div id="tblUseCommunities" class="dvOnlineCommunityMain">
```

So , Just change the selector to accommodate class instead ..

```
  var dvOnlineCommunityMain = $(".dvOnlineCommunityMain");
```

Comment: would know the answer as to why when the element is added to the div, when i refresh the page, the element disappears, seems like it happens for the remove also just like the append